# How do I fix this code that changes my bot's status every so often?

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js

I currently have this code that changes his custom status every 15 seconds, but right now my bot's status doesn't show and shows that he is online instead of idle. Nothing that I found worked because most everyone else used a different format than me for setting presence. What would I do to change this?

```js
client.on("ready", async () => {
  console.log("Ready!");
  const names = ["with Archigan and Terrain", "probably Risk of Rain 2"];
  const rand = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
  setInterval(
    () =>
      client.user!.setPresence({
        activity: {
          type: "PLAYING",
          name: rand,
        },
        status: "idle",
      }),
    1000 * 15
  );
  await reloadCommands();
});
```

Comment: it changes the bot status to 'idle' with certain activity (not random) every 15 secs based on your `setInterval`. What is it you want to fix again?

Comment: `user!` is not valid. Also changing status every 15 seconds could fall under Discord API spam

Comment: @Elitezen `user!` is valid, as this is typescript and not javascript. furthermore, `user` exists on a client.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, client.user!.setPresence() should be client.user.setPresence()

also, this is my code, and this works so yea

```
let activityOptions = [
        `${client.guilds.cache.size} servers and ${client.guilds.cache.reduce(
            (a, g) => a + g.memberCount,
            0
        )} members!`,
        `${client.nerdwars.randomKey(1)}`,
        `${client.commands.size} commands!`,
        `s.help!`
    ];

    setInterval(() => {
        client.user.setPresence({
            status: 'online',
            activity: {
                name:
                    activityOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * activityOptions.length)],
                type: 'WATCHING'
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: This is typescript, not javascript, so I have to use the non-null assignment operator, or `!`, after `user`.

Answer (score 0):

when pasting your code into my project it works fine although my vs code starts complaining about using " instead of '. this is because of the ESLint rules. other than that have you waited more than 15 seconds for it to update? when using the setInterval function it needs to finish the time before doing your first function call.

Also your rand variable won't update every 15 seconds because the assignment is only called once you could put this line `names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)]` inside the name property.